# Is function keyword optional while creating an object?

Tags: javascript

```js
       let username = {
            
            name: 'John Smith',
            yearBorn: 2001,
            
            age (){
                
                return 2020 - this.yearBorn;
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
    console.log(username.age());
```

As you can see, I'm not using function expression here nor I'm doing standard function by using the function keyword yet its working perfectly fine!

Is it safe to assume that function keyword is optional when you're creating a JS object?

Comment: Yes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: It wasn't optional in the past, but recent language changes included this convenience.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I believe the answer is true. I can go on without using function keyword but is this a good practice to do so?

Comment: @prettyversatile so long as you don't care about things like IE9 it's fine.

Comment: @Pointy - No version of IE has it, not even IE11. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This (property initialization with a function expression):

```
let username = {
    age: function() {
    }
};
```

and this (method syntax):

```
let username = {
    age() {
    }
};
```

do slightly different things, but often you don't care about the difference.

There are a couple of differences between a property initializer using a function and method syntax:

- With method syntax, the code within the method can use the `super` keyword to access things on its prototype object. When doing a property with a function expression initializer, it can't. Method syntax enables `super` by attaching the object you created the method on to the method as an internal field called [[HomeObject]] in the spec (you can't access internal fields); then `super.x` looks up the current prototype of the [[HomeObject]] and accesses `x` on it.
- With method syntax, the resulting function is just a function/method, not a *constructor* function. With the first code block above, you could do `new username.age()` and create an object; with the second, you couldn't. (And since they aren't constructor functions, methods don't have a `prototype` property with a mostly-empty object assigned to it.)

Method syntax was introduced in ES2015. It's present in all modern browsers, and not in obsolete browsers like Internet Explorer (not even IE11).

Comment: FWIW, methods are also not constructable.

Comment: @FelixKling - True! I'll add that. (I knew something was bothering me...) :-)

Comment: (All: FWIW, I cover method syntax in detail in Chapter 5 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.)